# How do I create a graphql query with filter?

Tags: graphql

I am a begginer in graphql and I am trying to query an item using a field as follows:

```
const listCountries = gql`
          query listCountries {
            listCountries {
              countries (where: { country_id: ${countryData.country_id} }) {
                id
                country_id
                country_name
              }
            }
          }
        `;
```

When I execute this, I am getting an error `"Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'listCountries' in type 'Query' is undefined @ 'listCountries'"`.

I have tried to modify the query but I am getting errors. How should it be modified to get country by country_id

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name - duplicated operation name?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I have used the following code.

```
const listCountries = gql`
            query listCountries {
              listCountrys(filter: {country_id: {eq: ${countryData.country_id}}}) {
                items {
                  id
                  country_id
                  country_name
                  _deleted
                }
              }
            }
          `;
```